# android Can't open file for reading

Tags: android, usb-debugging

Hi I created my first Hello World app and followed instructions as
posted on developer.android but when I connect my sony xperia s with
debugging enabled and run my app , i see in the logcat errors saying
"E/(4446): Can't open file for reading"  I am using the ADT plugin for
Eclipse

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MyMainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_my_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MyMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyMainActivity" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

any idea please what's causing the "can't open file" error thank you
for your support the full logcat stack

```
04-08 12:20:07.350: D/TextLayoutCache(4446): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
04-08 12:20:07.420: D/libEGL(4446): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-08 12:20:07.420: D/libEGL(4446): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
04-08 12:20:07.430: D/libEGL(4446): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
04-08 12:20:07.440: D/libEGL(4446): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
04-08 12:20:07.460: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(4446): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
04-08 12:20:07.470: D/memalloc(4446): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5c63d000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:64
04-08 12:20:07.480: E/(4446): Can't open file for reading
04-08 12:20:07.480: E/(4446): Can't open file for reading
04-08 12:20:07.480: D/OpenGLRenderer(4446): Enabling debug mode 0
04-08 12:20:07.550: D/memalloc(4446): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5ce2c000 size:33538048 offset:29769728 fd:67
04-08 12:20:33.110: D/OpenGLRenderer(4446): Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-08 12:20:33.130: D/memalloc(4446): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5c63d000 size:3768320 offset:0
04-08 12:20:33.130: D/memalloc(4446): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5ce2c000 size:33538048 offset:29769728
04-08 12:20:33.140: D/OpenGLRenderer(4446): Flushing caches (mode 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you see your "hello world" string when you run your application? There is nothing in the error to indicate that it is thrown by your application.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I do see the hello world and the application runs ok.

Comment: Then in most likelihood, it is not thrown by your application.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you checked permission(read, write, ...) to work with File.